# What should be burned to get ashes in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

I need ash to make healing salves. What is the best item to burn to get ash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always interesting to burn things that:

- Have no (great) other use ([@trollingchar's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/230513/trollingchar) example of water pool plants is excellent)
- Are renewable
- Are easy to farm
- Stack nicely

For these reasons, I most often burn **[twigs](https://dontstarve.fandom.com/wiki/Twigs)**:

- you can shovel [saplings](https://dontstarve.fandom.com/wiki/Sapling) easily and replant them,
- you can plant them close together and farm them fast by holding
  <kbd>SPACE</kbd>,
- they don't need manure to grow,
- and once you have 40 saplings planted, twigs come in aplenty.

Burning a stack of 40 twigs gives 40 ash.

Answer (score 3):

[Many items](https://dontstarve.fandom.com/wiki/Ashes) will do:

> *Ashes* are an Item that is dropped after a flammable object has been
>   burnt by *Fire* (some exceptions such as *Trees*), including the remnants
>   of a *Campfire* and a destroyed *Pig Torch* or *Fire Pit*.
>   *Ashes* will also
>   replace any item that is not allowed to be carried through to the next
>   World via the *Teleportato* (e.g. the *Eye Bone* or *Webber's Skull*).

And, more appropriately:

> **Due to their abundance and minimal use, *Pine Cones* and *Jungle Tree
>   Seeds* are good candidates to burn and get *Ashes*.**

As well as [**tree stumps**](https://dontstarve.fandom.com/wiki/Tree):

> *Stumps* that have been burned will turn into *Ashes*.

Comment: The page you referenced says: "Due to their abundance and minimal use, Pine Cones and Jungle Tree Seeds are good candidates to burn and get Ashes" which looks like an answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you @Underverse, you are a scholar and a gentleman (and I'm having an off day). Edited.

Comment: Also plants around water pools can be burned and it's the only way you can use them.